# Uninstalled apps still appear in settings

Tags: iphone, ios, applications

I have deleted an app with intentions of reinstalling, but when I clicked App Store and searched for the app, instead of showing the option to download it's showing "open" as if I still have the app. I've turned my phone off and back on multiple times but it's still there. Can anyone help get my app back? [image]

Comment: What happens if you tap on "Open"?

Comment: Nothing. It just keeps saying open

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1. Back up your iPhone (use a password on the backup)
2. Wipe your iPhone: settings > General > Reset > Erase All content and Settings
3. Restore your iPhone from the backup you just created.

The ghost icons should be gone

This whole procedure should take less than an hour. Possibly much less depending on how much needs to be backed up and if your Mac & iPhone support USB3 speeds.

Comment: Would you have to back up on iTunes, or is it safe to back up on iCloud ?

Comment: I always back up locally as it is a LOT faster. EG you are not constrained by the speed of your WiFi to your phone and the vagaries of download speeds imposed by your ISP. DO it locally, you'll be glad you did.

Comment: I’ve not backed up to anything but iCloud for several years. I’d say it’s as reliable or better than iTunes at this point - just not as fast if you don’t have a local caching server or an Apple data center close by in terms of internet speeds. @TrinYo