# device - IPhone X (ios 14) Problem regarding deleting an app

Tags: iphone

I have deleted an app with intentions of reinstalling, but when I clicked App Store and searched for the app, instead of showing the option to download it's showing "open" as if I still have the app. I've turned my phone off and back on multiple times but it's still there. Can anyone help get my app back?

[image]

Comment: Are you in India? https://www.imore.com/pubg-removed-app-store-and-google-play-store-following-ban-india

Comment: No I’m from bangladesh! It was working fine last night. But i deleted the app because i was running out of space in my phone. But the icon still showed up but didn’t open when i tried to. And in the app store it’s showing Open instead of Install!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uninstalled apps still appear in settings](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/262713/uninstalled-apps-still-appear-in-settings)